# Returning Structures in C++ from functions

Tags: c++, function, struct, return

I am trying to return a struct from a function and am having issues with the data types. I keep getting the complier error "No Suitable conversion function from "coefficients" to "int" exists "return coeff;"" from the code below. I have seen lots of people having these issues because they are defining the structure in the function, but mine is defined at the start. Any feedback would be great.

```
#include <iostream> //initialise the code familly used in most commands
using namespace std; //initialise the coding name space

struct coefficients {
    float A;
    float B;
    float C;
} coeff;

int matrix_multiplication(int r1,int r2,int r3,int r4,int r5) //matrix  multiplication between the readings taken and the regression matrix
{
float a1=3.2, b1=-2.8, c1=-0.8, d1=2.2, e1=-0.8; //teach the variables a1-a5   x a1 - d1 the values of the regression matrix
float a2=-3.0, b2=4.3, c2=0.9, d2=-3.4, e2=1.3;
float a3=0.9, b3=-1.6, c3=-0.1, d3=2.2, e3=-0.8;

coeff.A = (a1*r1)+(b1*r2)+(c1*r3)+(d1*r4)+(e1*r5);
coeff.B = (a2*r1)+(b2*r2)+(c2*r3)+(d2*r4)+(e2*r5);
coeff.C = (a3*r1)+(b3*r2)+(c3*r3)+(d3*r4)+(e3*r5);
return coeff;
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you declare `coefficiants matrix_multiplicaton`?

Comment: Also, do look into arrays!

Comment: In C++ a structure (or class) is not that different from the native types. You can return one just like any other value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
int matrix_multiplication(int r1,int r2,int r3,int r4,int r5)
```

to

```
coefficients matrix_multiplication(int r1,int r2,int r3,int r4,int r5)
//^^^^^^^^^^ <- You are returning a coefficients object, not an int.
```

because `return coeff` returns a `coefficients` object, not an `int`.

Also, try to use arrays to simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `matrix_multiplication` function is told to returning `int` value but you're trying to return another type. Should be like this instead:

```
coefficients matrix_multiplication(int r1,int r2,int r3,int r4,int r5) //matrix  multiplication between the readings taken and the regression matrix
```